Collating text in a worksheet from a seperate worksheet
I am using some downtime to create a spreadsheet to organize imported data.
What I am trying to do is extract text from cells on sheet 1 of a dynamic location of differing lengths that are consistently between two words.
In the formula below, I am looking for all text between "SearchTerm1" and "SearchTerm2". This could be 4 or 10 cells long and could be anywhere in the range specified.
So far I have come up with:
=FILTER((Sheet1!A1:Sheet1!Z250 = "SearchTerm1")*(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!Z250 = "SearchTerm2")), "No information")
This is only the start, as I need to do the same for multiple instances of the same word.
for example
=FILTER((Sheet1!A1:Sheet1!Z250 = "the first occurrence of a word")*(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!Z250 = "the second occurrence of the same word")), "No information")
Am I trying to do something that is not possible in ecel without using VBA? (which I find difficult)
thanks,
EDIT to Add:
I am using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2412 Build 16.0.18324.20092) 64-bit
I have been asked to post my dataset which is as followed and delimited by spaces:
Project   66 Marshes Parade, Casula    Run 0
Casula  PC 2170  Lat  -33.90  Long  150.90   Climate File Climat28.TXT

Dwelling
D P Number:          26304
Lot Number:          134
Street Number:       66
Unit Number:         
Street Name:         Marshes Parade
Development Name:    
Suburb:              Casula
State:               NSW
Postcode:            2170
NCC Class:           2

Plan
Plan Reference:      052/24 Rev E
Prepared By:         RHIZ0ME ST/AK

Assessor Details
Assessor Name:       My Name
AAO:                 Design Matters National
Assessor Number:     DMN/11/1111

Summary
Conditioned Area                 131.5 m² (126.7 m²)
Unconditioned Area               10.2 m² (8.9 m²)
Glazed Common Area               0.0 m² (0.0 m²)
Total Floor Area                 141.7 m² (135.6 m²)
Total Glazed Area                35.6 m²
Total External Solid door Area   1.8 m²
Glass to Floor Area              25.1 %
Gross External Wall Area         185.8 m²
Net External Wall Area           148.4 m²

Window
 2.4 m²  ALM-004-01 A DEFAULTS  Uval 4.80  SHGC 0.59
              Glass  Air Fill Clear-Clear
              Frame  ALM-004-01 A Aluminium B DG Air Fill Clear-Clear
10.1 m²  BRD-033-003-001 BRADNAMS  Uval 4.42  SHGC 0.62
              Glass  4EA
              Frame  Aluminium Sliding Door SG
11.6 m²  BRD-030-013-001 BRADNAMS  Uval 4.47  SHGC 0.51
              Glass  6.38CPClr
              Frame  Aluminium Hinged Door SG
 4.1 m²  BRD-112-001-001 BRADNAMS  Uval 6.54  SHGC 0.67
              Glass  4Clr
              Frame  Aluminium Awning Window SG
 5.0 m²  BRD-001-021-001 BRADNAMS  Uval 4.59  SHGC 0.67
              Glass  4ET
              Frame  Aluminium Sliding Window SG
 2.4 m²  BRD-112-005-001 BRADNAMS  Uval 5.19  SHGC 0.55
              Glass  4ET
              Frame  Aluminium Awning Window SG

External Wall
148.4 m²  Cavity Brick   R0.90 Bulk Insulation

Internal Wall
69.0 m²  Cavity brick  No Insulation both sides of Shaft liner
89.4 m²  Single Skin Brick  No Insulation
38.4 m²  Cavity brick  R 0.9 Bulk Insulation in the centre

External Floor
94.8 m²  Concrete Slab, Unit Below 150mm  Cork Tiles or Parquetry 8mm  No Insulation
2.4 m²  Concrete Slab on Ground 100mm  Cork Tiles or Parquetry 8mm  No Insulation

External Ceiling
41.5 m²  Concrete, Plasterboard with Timber Frame  R1.0 Bulk Insulation Unventilated roofspace
59.7 m²  Plasterboard on Timber  R4.0 Bulk Insulation Unventilated roofspace

Internal Floor/Ceiling
53.3 m²  Concrete Timber Framed Above Plasterboard  No Insulation

Roof (Horizontal area)
59.3 m²  Corrugated Iron Timber Frame  R 1.3 Bulk, Reflective Side Down, No Air Gap Above  35° slope   Skillion roof
37.9 m²  Corrugated Iron Timber Frame  R 1.3 Bulk, Reflective Side Down, No Air Gap Above  2° slope   Skillion roof

THE OUTPUT DESIRED in a separate sheet:
Project (inc DP number/Lot Number/Unit Number/Street number/Street Name/Development Name/Suburb/state/postcode)
Conditioned area value
Unconditioned area value
Glass to floor area value as percentage
Wall to floor area calculated as a percentage 
Window code and types listed with Uval & SHGC
External Wall Types and areas rounded
Internal Wall Types and areas rounded
External Floor Types Types and areas rounded
External Ceiling Types and areas rounded
Roof Types and areas 

Where a floor type is bare subtracted value from unconditioned area and list separately as Unconditioned excluding garage
the dataset can have up to 20 different windows and 10 different wall/floor/ceiling/roof types from project to project and this would change the format somewhat.

Please edit your question to include a data sample as text which can be copy/pasted and your expected output from that same data sample (the output can be a screenshot).

You may need MMULT() or BYROW(), BYCOL() functions. Post sample data and mention your Excel version.

And is all the data in Column A? If not, please use this Markdown Tables Generator so we can understand the layout better.

You should insert a helper column on your data into cell AA2:
=IF($A2 = "SearchTerm1", "Include", IF($A2 = "SearchTerm2", "", IF($AA1 = "Include", "Include", "")))

Then filter on "Include".
This works on the assumption that the search terms are not nested.
